# How to insert input into System.in?

Tags: java, junit

I'm doing a simple assignment that reads user input from `System.in`, but then it suddenly occurred to me that the assignment requires me to create jUnit test cases to confirm that it works properly.  So how can I simulate a user inserting input into `System.in` while sitting on a test case method?

Comment: You are going to need to accept more answers to other questions before someone will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your implementation do not use `System.in` directly, but rather use generic `InputStream`.

This way in your test class you can use `ByteArrayInputStream` with canned values.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom `InputStream` so that you can simulate what is read. You can set your implementation with `System.setIn(..)`

The simplest implementation would be to have the `read(..)` method that you use return something hard-coded. What exactly implementation you need depends on what you read from the System.in

Answer (score 1):

Put the following at the beginning of your test code:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter();
Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(writer.BaseStream));
```

Then you can write whatever you want to the Console.In stream via the writer object (e.g. writer.Write("whatever...") or writer.WriteLine("whatever...").